# jQuery binding via live doesn't work when selecting element by attribute in IE7 and IE8

Tags: jquery

The following code works in FF6, IE9, Safari and Chrome.  However, in IE7 and IE8, it looks like the click event is not being bound to anchor. Why?  Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/k865h/2/

```
$("a[data-my-item]").live('click', 
                      function () 
                      { 
                          return confirm("go to google?"); 
                      });
```

Note: I'm using IE9 and switching Browser Mode in Developer Tools to emulate IE7 & IE8 behavior. I can see that $("a[data-my-item]") selects the right DOM object but it looks like it doesn't bind 'click' event.

Comment: it seems to be working for me, i'm also testing using IE9 and changing the browser mode. I used jsfiddle to test it. http://jsfiddle.net/JcMzu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like IE7 and IE8 require that attribute has a value.  In my case it attribute has a value of empty string. If I populate it with anything it will start working.